# Построение траектории движения

Tags: python

У меня есть два массива с координатами - широта и долгота. Как с помощью библиотеки `geopandas` нанести на карту точки с заданными координатами и соединить их линией (чтоб получилась траектория движения)? Я как-то в интернетах не нашёл функций для этого. Вот пример того, что я хочу получить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы, очевидно, плохо искали. в вопросе должен быть ваш код и пример исходных данных.